# glGenBuffers - freeing memory?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

When I use glGenBuffers to create a VBO with a pointer to it, I (think) am allocating memory. Subsequent calls to glGenBuffers should return different pointes, but what about the memory previously allocated? In the Nehe examples I didn't see a "free memory" call... and I read that openGL is kind of a "state machine", does this mean that if my initializeBuffers() function is called several times I don't need to free anything and just use the glGenBuffers "as it is" ?

Comment: Note that what you get back from `glGenBuffers` is a set of "names" (some unspecified integers, as in "handles"), not pointers. Theoretically this could be continuously incrementing numbers, and OpenGL only remembers the last number it has given out (though in reality, it will probably also allocate some structures internally).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, theoretically numbers could overflow if I keep incrementing them without freeing them, right?

Comment: Well, if the driver implementation is _very naive_ and you actually allocate more than 4 billion buffers, yes... but a 32bit application would run out of address space needed to hold these numbers much earlier, and a 64bit application would need 16GB of virtual memory to store them, so... it's not one of the likely to occur problems either way :-)

Comment: I wonder why using VBO is advantageous while the data is stored in 2 places (in system memory and in GPU).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For any `glGenBuffers` call you do, you have to do a corresponding [`glDeleteBuffers`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDeleteBuffers) call.

Note that the pointer you pass to `glGenBuffers` is not allocated/deallocated. In fact, it could even be these calls do not actually allocate anything in cpu memory, but you have no guarantee of that either.

What you pass to `glGenBuffers` is an already-allocated array (or single value) that will store the "name" you reference a gpu-resource by, the workflow looks like this:

```
GLuint buffer; //Note: statically allocated
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer); // Allocate a GPU-resource - only updates value in buffer
//Work a bit with buffer
glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer); //Deallocate the gpu-resource
```

The reason `buffer` is passed as a pointer is because you can create multiple buffers, e.g. like this:

```
GLuint buffer[3]; //Note: again statically allocated
glGenBuffers(3, &buffer); // Allocate a GPU-resource - update values in buffer
//Work a bit with buffer
glDeleteBuffers(3, &buffer); //Deallocate the gpu-resource
```

Of course, `buffer` could very well be dynamically allocated by you, e.g.:

```
std::vector<GLuint> buffer(3); //std::vector uses dynamic allocation
glGenBuffers(3, &buffer[0]); // Allocate a GPU-resource - update values in buffer
//Work a bit with buffer
glDeleteBuffers(3, &buffer[0]); //Deallocate the gpu-resource
```